# `npm run test` giving error while import using paths

Tags: angular, npm-build

tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {     
  "themes/*": [
    "assets/themes/*"
  ]
}
```

projects\myplugin\src\lib\modules\home\components\detail.component.less

```
@import 'themes/theme.less';
```

this import working while build and package publish but not working in npm run test.

Error:

```
@import 'themes/theme.less';
^
Less resolver error:
Webpack resolver error details:
resolve 'themes/theme.less'
```

Comment: please share what test framework you are using and any configuration file of that framework.

Comment: @nazrul-chowdhury nothing special in testing framework. I am just trying npm run test command for my pluging

Comment: which test runner is being run?

Comment: default , not added any other

Comment: jest? Am i correct in assuming this ?

Comment: Yes, if it is default

Comment: please add your jest.config.js with your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254493/discussion-between-hitesh-thakor-and-nazrul-chowdhury).

Comment: can't join chat atm. sorry. i have added an answer based on pure assumption.

Answer (score 1):

update your jest.config.js and add module mapper

```js
module.exports = {
  // other configurations...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^themes/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/assets/themes/$1'
  }
}
```